# Powermock - @SuppressStaticInitializationFor affecting the unit-test of actual static class to be tested in a single run for all test classes

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a class **X** with all static methods. And an app **A** to test the behavior of this class.
I have separate unit tests for both.
Note: I have to strictly adhere to writing separate unit tests for both.

Suppressing the static initialization for the class **A** is affecting unit tests of the class **X** for which I'm doing `mockstatic` in class **A**.

I'm not sure of the scope of `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem when turning to PowerMock to fix problems introduced by unwise usage of **static**. Keep in mind: **static** is an **abnormality** within good OO design - as it breaks (easy) unit testing, polymorphism, and leads to direct coupling of your classes!

So my advise here: simply avoid using *static* in a way that leads you to ask for PowerMock in order to do unit testing. In other words: instead of using PowerMock, learn how to create **testable** code (you can start [here)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)) and then create production code that can be tested with Mockito or EasyMock ... without any super Powers needed.

If you can't do that: at the very minimum, make sure that you **never** create static init code that breaks your unit test environment. It is a fair request to your development team to come up with **production** classes that can at least be **loaded** by JUnit tests.